# Setting dropdown height of a combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a combobox in WPF that I add items to at run-time (via a data binding to a List).  I'd like to set the height of the dropdown box dynamically so that all (or most) of the items show.  Unfortunately it seems that the height of the dropdown is set once and cannot be dynamically altered.  It always seems to be the same size.

Is there some relatively straightforward to adjust the dropdown height?

---

Yes, I've tried setting it after adding the items to the combobox.  In the debugger it looks like the new value is there. However, when I open the dropdown, it drops down to a size of its own choosing.  I've tried exaggerating the MaxDropDownHeight and have even set it to "Auto" to no avail.

Answer (score 18):

The property `MaxDropDownHeight` is a dependency property, on the combo box that controls the height of the drop down list. Since it's a dependency property, it's value can be set dynamically.

Have you tried setting this value?

```
MaxDropDownHeight="Auto"
```

Comment: The reason this is not a good answer is because he's databinding to a List.  I don't know why, but MaxDropDownHeight has no effect when binding to a list.  If you change to an ObservableCollection, like what @kimmoli said, it works.

Answer (score 11):

For me, the issue was that ComboBox dropdown had height of 95 pixels regardles of the amount of items.

My data source for the ComboBox was a `Collection<>`, but after changing it to `ObservableCollection<>`, the ComboBox dropdown opens showing all items.

Now also the `MaxDropDownHeight` property works just fine.

Ref: This comment in here [Make the dropdown of a combobox be shorter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302874/make-the-dropdown-of-a-combobox-be-shorter#comment14889455_11302915)

Comment: I used MaxDropDownHeight

Comment: It seems like the collection needs to be an `ObservableCollection` in order to allow the dropdown to resize itself.

Comment: @Maxence you are god :)  you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Set your ComboBox's Style={x:Null} to ensure that you don't have a style issue affecting the drop-down panel size.