# Make the dropdown of a combobox be shorter?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Mildly confused. I have a combobox that is databound to a list of strings. In the past I recall the combobox being short if I only had one or two things in it. But now the combobox is about the height of 5 items, even when there's less than 5 items (the height of a blank drop down). What do I need to change to fix this? I've played with Maxdropdown with no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx), if your control is already styled with a costom template it could be the case that the `MaxDropDownHeight` property is not properly bound inside the template, in this case changing it will not do anything.

Comment: The solution I was looking for was much simpler. It's fixed if I bind it to an observablecollection rather than a list

Comment: @cost: Something like that really should not matter, weird implementation in that case...

Comment: I used MaxDropDownHeight

Answer (score 0):

well, you cannot do this easily, this is hardcoded in the comboBox's template:

```
      <Trigger Property="HasItems"
               Value="false">
        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                Property="MinHeight"
                Value="95" />
      </Trigger>
```

(source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094 - this is not exactly the template used in WPF per say, but I'm assuming they haven't changed this behavior)

so you would indeed have to redo the comboBox's template yourself, and this is no easy stuff.